# CSS3/Jquery text slide up animation missing extra frame

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to recreate the following slide up effect: http://sanfrancisco.themerella.com/

There's currently a missing extra slide up animation (after the slide in) the text has appeared on screen. As a result, it looks a bit jilted. Also there's a pause in the beginning which is a bit awkward. This is my code so far:

**JQUERY**

```
var count = -1;

function ticker() {
  var ticker = $('.keyword');
  var tickerLength = ticker.length - 1;
  count < tickerLength ? count++ : count = 0;
  ticker.removeClass('text-slide-in active').eq(count).addClass('text-slide-in active');
}
setInterval(ticker, 2000);
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="section-title section-title-default align-center ra_section_title_5a7d898037b3b vc_custom_1509637288809 text-slide-activated" data-plugin-textslide="true" data-plugin-textslide-options='{"element":"div","autoplay":true,"delay":2000}'>
  <div>
    <span class="typed-keywords">Connecting Brands with
                          <span class="keyword">YouTubers.</span>
    <span class="keyword">Creatives.</span>
    <span class="keyword">Infuencers.</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS3**

```
.typed-keywords {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-transform-style: flat;
  transform-style: flat;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px
}

.typed-keywords .keyword {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  opacity: 0
}

.typed-keywords .keyword:first-child {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  opacity: 1
}

.text-slide-activated .typed-keywords .keyword {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0
}

.text-slide-activated .typed-keywords .keyword.text-slide-up {
  -webkit-animation: textSlideUp 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) both alternate;
  animation: textSlideUp 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) both alternate
}

.text-slide-activated .typed-keywords .keyword.active {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: textSlideIn 0.6s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) both alternate;
  animation: textSlideIn 0.6s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) both alternate
}

@keyframes textSlideUp {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -85%, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 35deg);
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes textSlideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 85%, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -35deg);
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pd3easvf/6/.

Comment: The way that site handles it, which would be the best way in my opinion, is to put all the words in a container, then dynamically change the width of the container to match the next word. You could do the same effect with CSS only, but you'll need to have fixed widths for the container and set the width to sync with the different blocks of text you're bringing in. You also might want to consider using a single keyframe on and off, and using an animation delay for each block of text, using transition instead of margin to move the up.

Comment: @ChrisMorris I've just updated the question, just as you answered. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a jquery plugin called [wordsrotator](https://github.com/andreapace/wordsrotator) that can do just that.

Sorry I put all in the snippet but I didn't find a CDN for the project.

```js
(function($){$.fn.wordsrotator=function(options){var defaults={autoLoop:true,randomize:false,stopOnHover:false,changeOnClick:false,words:null,animationIn:"flipInY",animationOut:"flipOutY",speed:2000};var settings=$.extend({},defaults,options);var listItem
var array_bak=[];return this.each(function(){var el=$(this)
var cont=$("#"+el.attr("id"));var array=[];if((settings.words)||(settings.words instanceof Array)){array=$.extend(true,[],settings.words);if(settings.randomize)array_bak=$.extend(true,[],array);listItem=0
if(settings.randomize)listItem=Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)
cont.html(array[listItem]);var rotate=function(){cont.html("<span class='wordsrotator_wordOut'><span>"+array[listItem]+"</span></span>");if(settings.randomize){array.splice(listItem,1);if(array.length==0)array=$.extend(true,[],array_bak);listItem=Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);}else{if(array.length==listItem+1)listItem=-1;listItem++;}
$("<span class='wordsrotator_wordIn'>"+array[listItem]+"</span>").appendTo(cont);cont.wrapInner("<span class='wordsrotator_words' />");cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordOut").addClass("animated "+settings.animationOut);cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordIn").addClass("animated "+settings.animationIn);};cont.on("click",function(){if(settings.changeOnClick){rotate();return false;};});if(settings.autoLoop){var t=setInterval(rotate,settings.speed);if(settings.stopOnHover){cont.hover(function(){window.clearInterval(t)},function(){t=setInterval(rotate,settings.speed);});};}};});}}(jQuery));

$(function() {
  var words = [
    'YouTubers',
    'Creatives',
    'Influencers'
  ];

  $("#rotate").wordsrotator({
    words: words,
    animationIn: "fadeInDown",
    animationOut: "fadeOutDown",
  });
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.wordsrotator_words{display:inline-block; position:relative; white-space:nowrap;  -webkit-transition:width 1s;  -moz-transition:width 1s;  -o-transition:width 1s;  transition:width 1s}
.wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordOut, .wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordIn{position:relative; display:inline-block; -webkit-animation-duration:1s; -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease; -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both; -moz-animation-duration:1s; -moz-animation-timing-function:ease; -moz-animation-fill-mode:both; -ms-animation-duration:1s; -ms-animation-timing-function:ease; -ms-animation-fill-mode:both}
.wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordOut{left:0; top:0; position:absolute; display:inline-block}
.wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordOut span{width:auto; position:relative}
.wordsrotator_words .wordsrotator_wordIn{opacity:0}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <span class="typed-keywords">Connecting Brands with <span id="rotate"></span> </span>
  </div>
</header>

<link href="https://fastcdn.org/Animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreapace/wordsrotator/master/jquery.wordrotator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreapace/wordsrotator/master/jquery.wordrotator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```